# formula for date to fill its self out but results stay hidden when date is blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have made a spreadsheet that when I put in the date at the top of the header it automatically fills in the rest of the spreadsheet. BUT, I would like for the results to stay hidden when there is not a date entered..as of now F5 is my date that has to be entered. B8 thru B43 is the remaining dates. when there is no data in F5 B8 and down show 1/1/1900.. I am putting in B8 (=F5) then in B9 and down is (=B8+1).. what else do I need to put with this formula to hide the 1/1/1900 when nothing is entered in F5

Answer (score 0):

In B8 use this formula

`=IF(F5="","",B8)`

and then in B9 copied down

`=IF(B8="","",B8+1)`

Comment: Thanks the b9 formula worked great but the b8 did not.. however with the formula you gave I'm starting to understand a little more about the formulas.. not near enough but some.. lol.. thank you for the formulas tho.. it helped me a lot..

Comment: Sorry, I referred to the wrong cell - B8 formula should refer to F5 not B8, like this `=IF(F5="","",F5)` the two quotes "" indicates a blank cell so the formula says "if F5 is blank return a blank, otherwise return the value from F5"

Answer (score 0):

You should use IF function - it shows some value in a cell based on some criterion that you set. in this case it could be:

```
=IF(F5>0,F5,"")
```

The general use of this formula is like this:

```
IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])
```

I find it very useful as you can also nest such formulae if need be.

Comment: the previous advice I got helped half way.. his b9 formula worked but not the b8 so with all the advice I was getting between this post and another I posted a hour before I tried putting b8's formula together on my own.. didn't get it but I realized I got really close after putting your formula in.. yours worked for my b8 formula.. all tho I am really trying to learn more about formulas im way out of my element here.. hahaha what I really need is a break down of exactly what the formula means.. example:=IF(F5>0,F5,"")- to me all I understand is F5 is greater than 0. the (,) and ("") baffle me

Comment: Date values are stored in Excel as numbers. For example date 01/01/2010 in Excel is 40179. It is you telling the cell format is date that displays it as date. Consequence - these numbers can be compared, therefore `if F5 > 0` means if date cell value above 0. It will work if your dates are after 1st January 1900 (the zero point). Consequently `if F5 =< 0` then display "". `""` is standard notation for empty string of characters - so nothing gets displayed. I hope this is clearer now ;) Formulas are quite well explained in help, just look at parameters as in second line above - and experiment.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other answers, that require you to *change* the formula in every cell, you could apply *conditional formatting* to the respective cells instead. You could, for instance, set the text color to white when the value is 0 (1/1/1900).

(Dates in Excel are stored as numbers. The number of days since 1/1/1900. It is only the formatting that is applied to that cell which makes it display as a date.)

Comment: thanks, your way was pretty simple but not only was I trying to get this spreadsheet done I still like to learn how to do formulas.. but If I get in a bind again your way will be my crutch.. lol